# Create a function in R that accomplishes the following

Tags: r

Columns A - F are identity columns - (1,0). Column G has the values "WLB0", "WLB2": "WLB10" and "WLB46", "WLB89".

I am trying to do the following for every permutation of A-F with Column G

I am looking for a function to call instead of doing it using this very awkward code that I wrote.

the test data is available for download at the bottom.

```
X1 <- {dd <- subset(TEST, TEST$A == 1 & TEST$G =="WLB10"); de <-transform(dd, RP = sum(dd$I)/sum(dd$H));mean(de$RP)}

X2 <- {dd <- subset(TEST, TEST$A == 1 & TEST$G =="WLB8"); de <-transform(dd, RP = sum(dd$I)/sum(dd$H));mean(de$RP)}

X3 <- {dd <- subset(TEST, TEST$B == 1 & TEST$G =="WLB10"); de <-transform(dd, RP = sum(dd$I)/sum(dd$H));mean(de$RP)}

TEST1$finalnumber <-ifelse(TEST1$A == 1 & TEST1$G == "WLB10", X1,

                       ifelse(TEST1$A == 1 & TEST1$G == "WLB8", X2,

                              ifelse(TEST1$B == 1 & TEST1$G == "WLB10", X3, 0)))
```

Test data

"https://s3.amazonaws.com/RProgramming/TEST.csv"

"https://s3.amazonaws.com/RProgramming/TEST1.csv"

Comment: Why are you taking the mean of 1 value? `mean(de$RP)`

Comment: It is the mean of the sum(dd$I)/sum(dd$H). I did this to make it a scalar value. In the larger data set there is more than 1.

Comment: No, this is always a scalar! `sum` returns a scalar.

Comment: If I run > transform(dd, RP = sum(dd$I)/sum(dd$H)) - I end up with this: 

transform(dd, RP = sum(dd$I)/sum(dd$H))

    A B C D E F     G H I        RP

29  1 0 0 0 0 0 WLB10 1 1 0.5675676

60  1 0 0 0 0 0 WLB10 1 1 0.5675676

82  1 0 0 0 0 0 WLB10 1 0 0.5675676

When I run the mean I get the one number that I need. 
> mean(de$RP)

[1] 0.5675676

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about the purpose of setting RP to be constant across the rows of `de`, but the below bit of code will get you some way along, I hope.  `ddply` and `melt` are two great functions for this sort of thing

```
library(plyr)
library(reshape)
long <-  melt(TEST, measure.vars=LETTERS[1:6])
#long <- subset(variable==1)
shorter <- ddply(long, .(G, variable, value), summarize, RP=sum(I)/sum(H))
```

You can uncomment the line to just get subtotals corresponding to *1*, but I thought it was illustrative to show you how it works.

You can then do a similar melt on TEST1, and carry out a lookup for the relevant value:

```
long <-  melt(TEST1, measure.vars=LETTERS[1:6])
ind <-  match(paste0(long$G, long$variable), paste0(shorter$G, shorter$variable))
long$final <- shorter$RP[ind]
```